# Getting error "empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words" on implementation of CountVectorizer()

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding, countvectorizer

I am trying to perform a one-hot encoding of a categorical variable using CountVectorizer(). I am able to implement that on all the columns except one column named "Drill Centre". This column contains three unique value 'A', 'B', 'C'. When I am implementing CountVectorizer on this column then it gives me an error of **empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words**

```
vec=CountVectorizer()
train_drill=vec.fit_transform(X_train['Drill Centre']).toarray()
test_drill=vec.transform(X_test['Drill Centre']).toarray()
```

[image]

Comment: Count vectorizer doesn't generate one-hot encodings. It generates ngrams.

Comment: With categorical data CountVectorizer() works like OneHotEncoder().

Comment: Why not use a one-hot encoder directly: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

Comment: CountVectorizer have a tokenizer pattern in it (a param) that won't recognize single letters as words. This is why empty vocab.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Count vectorizer with categorical data creates sparse representations, not one-hot representations. If you want one-hot, use one-hot like @Metropolis suggests.

Comment: @Metropolis Thank you. I Will use one-hot-encoder but I was just curious that why is CountVectorizer() not working here.

Comment: As @SergeyBushmanov said, the CountVectorizer ignores single letters; it treats them as 'stop words.' CountVectorizer is meant to deal with natural language data: with words and sentences.